# MongoDB Aggregation: Combine two arrays

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following type of documents stored in a collection.

```
{
  "_id" : "318036:2014010100",
  "data": [
    {"flow": [6, 10, 12], "occupancy": [0.0356, 0.06, 0.0856], time: 0},
    {"flow": [2, 1, 4], "occupancy": [0.01, 0.0056, 0.0422], time: 30},
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to compute an aggregated value from the first, second, ..., nth value in the flow and occupancy arrays. The order within the array should be preserved. Assuming I want compute the sum. The result should look like the following:

```
{
  "_id" : "318036:2014010100",
  "data": [
    {"flow": [6, 10, 12], "occupancy": [0.0356, 0.06, 0.0856], sum: [6.0356, 10.006, 12.00856], time: 0},
    {"flow": [2, 1, 4], "occupancy": [0.01, 0.0056, 0.0422], sum: [2.01, 1.0056, 4.0422], time: 30},
    ...
  ]
}
```

I tried to solve this by using the aggregation framework but my current approach does not preserve the ordering and produces to much sums.

```
db.sens.aggregate([ 
  {$match: {"_id":/^318036:/}}, 
  {$limit: 1}, 
  {$unwind: "$data"}, 
  {$unwind: "$data.flow"}, 
  {$unwind: "$data.occupancy"}, 
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: {id: "$_id", time: "$data.time", o: "$data.occupancy", f: "$data.flow", s: {$add: ["$data.occupancy", "$data.flow"]}}
    }
  }, 
  {
    $group: { 
      _id: {id: "$_id.id", time: "$_id.time"}, occ: { $addToSet: "$_id.o"}, flow: {$addToSet: "$_id.f"}, speed: {$addToSet: "$_id.s"} 
    }
  } 
])
```

I am not sure if it is possible to solve this problem with the aggregation framework, so a solution using MapReduce would also be fine. How can I produce the desired result?

Comment: I believe this https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5919 prevents you from solving the problem with the aggregation framework. On the other hand, it is totally possible to do it with map reduce.

Comment: I'm personally a little bit baffled as to what you expect from a result. "Sets" are not ordered. The CTO says so himself and this is basically a general math principle. The "dual pump" on `$group` her e is not necessary since it can be done in one stage. Which basically bring me back to "what do you want to achieve" as a result given your original input? Doesn't seem to be clearly stated.

Comment: I do not believe there is a way to do this in the 2.6 aggregation framework. Consider map/reduce or client-side (pre-)processing.

Comment: if I understand correctly the question, there's no need to use neither aggregation framework nor map/reduce. Iterating the right documents and updating each of them as you need.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution with neither aggregation framework nor map/reduce:

```
db.sens.find().forEach(function (doc) {
   doc.data.forEach(function(dataElement) {
      var sumArray = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < dataElement.flow.length; j++) {
         sumArray[j] = dataElement.flow[j] + dataElement.occupancy[j];
      }
      dataElement.sum = sumArray;
      collection.save(doc);
   });
});
```